# Use withType() for configuring Gradle task not compiling in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure the *Test* task inside a custom Gradle plugin written in Java.

Applying the plugins I need like so in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `maven-publish`
}
```

I can compile the code successfully through the command line as in `./gradlew clean build`

But, **IntelliJ** complains about `Test.class` in the following code:

```
public static void configureTesting(final Project project) {
    project.getTasks().withType(Test.class).configureEach(task -> {
    });
}
```

Saying:

```
Required type: java.lang.Class <S>
Provided: java.lang.Class <Test>
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that T conforms to Task
```

I import the *Test* class like this:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test;
```

Gradle version: **6.7.1**

IntelliJ: **2020.2.3**

Comment: `But, IntelliJ complains about Test.class in the following code:` where it complains about it  - when build from IDE or in Editor only? Can you provide a sample project?

Comment: I can try to extract the code soon. But, to answer you question: It's underlined (a red line) in the editor window. I can build the project without problems. In Preferences, Build and run is set to Gradle. Tried to switch Gradle instance in there as well, but no luck when it comes to the editor underlining the code with a red line.

Comment: Please report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project.

Comment: @Andrey I will probably report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some (a lot of) time googling this. Eventually I found a comment somewhere saying that one could try to use the internal SDK (jbr) that ships with IntelliJ instead of a manually downloaded SDK. That made it work. The internal SDK is Java 11 and I've also installed the latest version of Java 11 from Oracle. Even though they are both Java 11, the internal SDK (jbr) is working as it should, but not the external SDK. For other projects the external SDK is working fine, but not for building a Gradle plugin.